# Kia Sorento push start revs much too high

Tags: starting, kia, electronics, sorento

Worked on cars for years, then fell away from doing anything besides replacing the occasional starter or oil pump, then nothing as my cars got more reliable.

My 2013 Kia Sorento is the newest car I've had so far.  The push-button start works fine but the initial "rev" of the engine is way too high.  About 2.5k RPM.

No long-term problems and it settles down to 600-800 RPM within a few seconds but wow, I would never start an engine with that much rev.  Perhaps old-school that you start your engine with minimal rev to allow oil pressure to build up.

Is there any way to adjust the initial idle speed on start-up for that model?  I've seen resources on the push-button not working but not specifically for programming the starting rev.  Thanks!

Comment: I think this is the way that Hyundai/Kia does their startup. Had a 2008 Azera and it did the same thing. It wasn't a push button start, but would find on key crank, the engine would spring to life to around 2500-ish rpm and stay there for a few seconds before it would settle down to just above 1k. Once the engine had been running for a minute or so, it would drop down to normal idle speeds. You could take the vehicle to a tuner and have them do something with it, but beyond that, nothing as an "average" person.

Comment: Probably less of an issue with modern synthetics but I'd try and avoid leaving it sitting for a month with a start like that. @Paulster2 "take it to a tuner" - you mean the dealer, or whom?

Comment: I mean, someone who can put a tune into your vehicles ECU, which would not be the dealer. You'd have to find someone who could modify the original tune in the ECU, which may not be very easy considering this is usually done for hi-performance applications. Probably not too common on a Sorento.

Comment: Tried Hyundai Kia Sorrento forums for an expert on EFI systems that might have expert info?